# Copying from one Excel to another : index out of valid range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy from one Excel workbook to another. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
directory = "C:\VBA\Import\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks(directory & fileName).Worksheets(1).Columns(1)
Set targetColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IMPORT").Columns(1)
sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
```

When executing this I get a "runtime error 9: index out of valid range" (translated from the German version of Excel) in the line with "set sourceColumn".

I can't figure out the reason for this. I double checked the filename using the debugger during execution and it's correct. Also the indexes for worksheet and column exist in this file (it has a single worksheet with 5 columns).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you opening the workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this, it works for me:

```
Workbooks.Open directory & Filename
Set sourceColumn = Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(1).Columns(1)
```

You can't reference to a closed workbook like that

Comment: Ah well and here I thought it would open the file automatically ;-) Thanks, works perfectly fine now